# Can I inject an ArcContainer instead of access it over the static method Arc.container()?

Tags: quarkus

Currently when I am in need to get some context information, e.g. if a certain context is active, I have to access the arc container as following `Arc.container()`.

As this does work, it is a pain for unit tests as mocking static methods is very annoying and hurts its readability.
Is there a way, which I couldn't find yet, to `@Inject` an `ArcContainer`? This way I could mock the field as usual.

The other option would be a helper bean which wraps the Arc access.

Comment: What you can inject is the `BeanManager`, which provides access to a lot of things that `ArcContainer` also exposes. Can you perhaps use that? But providing a bean for the `ArcContainer` is not a bad idea either. If `BeanManager` doesn't suit your needs, I suggest you file a feature request in the Quarkus issue tracker: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues